# "Random" mac crash on semaphore

Tags: macos, crash, osx-mavericks

I've been trying to fix a show-stopping bug for the last 2 months. I'm getting desperate!

My application often beachballs at some point within the first 5-10 seconds of starting up. The problem only occurs on Mavericks and I *think* the problem is limited to MacBook Pros since I'm not yet aware of a case on another Mac. On some machines it's systematic, on others it's not.

The hang can occur at any moment and it's always the result of a wait on a semaphore. Below are 3 different reports to demonstrate the problem (thanks to the sampling feature of the activity monitor).

On my laptop the problem occurs after a reboot, but subsequent attempts often work, which makes debugging even harder. I currently have access to a laptop on which a hang happens nearly every time. Nevertheless, even with XCode I can't nail down the issue since it appears to come from the OS. Sometimes the sample report's trackback doesn't include any of my code at all!

I removed tons of code to try to see if I'm doing something during initialisation that it doesn't like, but it makes no difference.

Does anyone here have any idea?

```
  2357 Thread_235557   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)
    + 2357 ???  (in The Touch)  load address 0x105044000 + 0x2224  [0x105046224]
    +   2357 ???  (in The Touch)  load address 0x105044000 + 0x2252  [0x105046252]
    +     2357 NSApplicationMain  (in AppKit) + 940  [0x7fff8d6cb803]
    +       2357 -[NSApplication run]  (in AppKit) + 553  [0x7fff8d6e09cc]
    +         2357 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]  (in AppKit) + 122  [0x7fff8d6ec8db]
    +           2357 _DPSNextEvent  (in AppKit) + 1434  [0x7fff8d6ed28e]
    +             2357 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter  (in HIToolbox) + 65  [0x7fff88e13abc]
    +               2357 ReceiveNextEventCommon  (in HIToolbox) + 173  [0x7fff88e13b85]
    +                 2357 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode  (in HIToolbox) + 226  [0x7fff88e13f0d]
    +                   2357 CFRunLoopRunSpecific  (in CoreFoundation) + 309  [0x7fff8a566275]
    +                     2357 __CFRunLoopRun  (in CoreFoundation) + 814  [0x7fff8a5667de]
    +                       2357 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks  (in CoreFoundation) + 341  [0x7fff8a566ee5]
    +                         2357 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__  (in CoreFoundation) + 12  [0x7fff8a5757cc]
    +                           2357 ___LSScheduleNotificationFunction_block_invoke_2  (in LaunchServices) + 47  [0x7fff867bce19]
    +                             2357 applicationStatusSubsystemCallback  (in AppKit) + 455  [0x7fff8df524db]
    +                               2357 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]  (in Foundation) + 68  [0x7fff8d38e4aa]
    +                                 2357 _CFXNotificationPost  (in CoreFoundation) + 2893  [0x7fff8a506c5d]
    +                                   2357 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__  (in CoreFoundation) + 12  [0x7fff8a612fcc]
    +                                     2357 ???  (in The Touch)  load address 0x105044000 + 0x4b13  [0x105048b13]
    +                                       2357 -[NSRunningApplication processIdentifier]  (in AppKit) + 116  [0x7fff8df5616e]
    +                                         2357 -[NSRunningApplication _fetchDynamicProperties]  (in AppKit) + 492  [0x7fff8da4abf8]
    +                                           2357 _LSCopyApplicationInformation  (in LaunchServices) + 2469  [0x7fff867b1bfe]
    +                                             2357 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync  (in libxpc.dylib) + 195  [0x7fff8c624733]
    +                                               2357 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 206  [0x7fff8834ba15]
    +                                                 2357 semaphore_wait_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff85b6aa56]





    2348 Thread_237480   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)
    + 2348 ???  (in The Touch)  load address 0x103b6a000 + 0x2224  [0x103b6c224]
    +   2348 ???  (in The Touch)  load address 0x103b6a000 + 0x2252  [0x103b6c252]
    +     2348 NSApplicationMain  (in AppKit) + 940  [0x7fff8d6cb803]
    +       2348 -[NSApplication run]  (in AppKit) + 646  [0x7fff8d6e0a29]
    +         2348 -[NSApplication sendEvent:]  (in AppKit) + 2021  [0x7fff8d890744]
    +           2348 -[NSStatusBarWindow sendEvent:]  (in AppKit) + 247  [0x7fff8d9ed11b]
    +             2348 -[NSWindow sendEvent:]  (in AppKit) + 11296  [0x7fff8d8f1d08]
    +               2348 ???  (in The Touch)  load address 0x103b6a000 + 0x144081  [0x103cae081]
    +                 2348 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:]  (in AppKit) + 327  [0x7fff8d90b3d0]
    +                   2348 ???  (in The Touch)  load address 0x103b6a000 + 0x4715  [0x103b6e715]
    +                     2348 ???  (in The Touch)  load address 0x103b6a000 + 0x458e  [0x103b6e58e]
    +                       2348 _NSSetCharValueAndNotify  (in Foundation) + 270  [0x7fff8d3e7ed9]
    +                         2348 ???  (in The Touch)  load address 0x103b6a000 + 0xcb729  [0x103c35729]
    +                           2348 ???  (in The Touch)  load address 0x103b6a000 + 0xd39a3  [0x103c3d9a3]
    +                             2348 -[NSApplication activateIgnoringOtherApps:]  (in AppKit) + 87  [0x7fff8d886f9e]
    +                               2348 -[NSApplication currentSystemPresentationOptions]  (in AppKit) + 33  [0x7fff8da86a93]
    +                                 2348 _GetActiveSystemUIModeAndOptions  (in HIToolbox) + 48  [0x7fff88f8beb8]
    +                                   2348 GetModeAndOptionsForProcess(__LSASN const*, unsigned int*, unsigned int*)  (in HIToolbox) + 34  [0x7fff88de70d5]
    +                                     2348 _LSCopyApplicationInformation  (in LaunchServices) + 2469  [0x7fff867b1bfe]
    +                                       2348 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync  (in libxpc.dylib) + 195  [0x7fff8c624733]
    +                                         2348 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 206  [0x7fff8834ba15]
    +                                           2348 semaphore_wait_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff85b6aa56]



    2297 Thread_238176   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)
    + 2297 ???  (in The Touch)  load address 0x103d46000 + 0x2224  [0x103d48224]
    +   2297 ???  (in The Touch)  load address 0x103d46000 + 0x2252  [0x103d48252]
    +     2297 NSApplicationMain  (in AppKit) + 940  [0x7fff8d6cb803]
    +       2297 -[NSApplication run]  (in AppKit) + 553  [0x7fff8d6e09cc]
    +         2297 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]  (in AppKit) + 122  [0x7fff8d6ec8db]
    +           2297 _DPSNextEvent  (in AppKit) + 1434  [0x7fff8d6ed28e]
    +             2297 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter  (in HIToolbox) + 65  [0x7fff88e13abc]
    +               2297 ReceiveNextEventCommon  (in HIToolbox) + 173  [0x7fff88e13b85]
    +                 2297 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode  (in HIToolbox) + 226  [0x7fff88e13f0d]
    +                   2297 CFRunLoopRunSpecific  (in CoreFoundation) + 309  [0x7fff8a566275]
    +                     2297 __CFRunLoopRun  (in CoreFoundation) + 776  [0x7fff8a5667b8]
    +                       2297 __CFRunLoopDoObservers  (in CoreFoundation) + 391  [0x7fff8a575017]
    +                         2297 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__  (in CoreFoundation) + 23  [0x7fff8a5750a7]
    +                           2297 __83-[NSWindow _postWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraintsUnlessPostingDisabled]_block_invoke1331  (in AppKit) + 46  [0x7fff8de5dcd1]
    +                             2297 _handleWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraints  (in AppKit) + 892  [0x7fff8d8898a6]
    +                               2297 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop  (in CoreFoundation) + 50  [0x7fff8a52ed72]
    +                                 2297 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 502  [0x7fff8e9d365a]
    +                                   2297 -[CIContext dealloc]  (in CoreImage) + 25  [0x7fff863a9789]
    +                                     2297 -[CIContext invalidate]  (in CoreImage) + 36  [0x7fff863a9812]
    +                                       2297 -[CICLContextImpl setOwner:]  (in CoreImage) + 38  [0x7fff863a6a81]
    +                                         2297 -[CICLContextImpl invalidate]  (in CoreImage) + 95  [0x7fff863a694f]
    +                                           2297 -[FEOpenCLContext dealloc]  (in CoreImage) + 17  [0x7fff863e4ea7]
    +                                             2297 FEOpenCLContextFinalize(FEOpenCLContext*)  (in CoreImage) + 363  [0x7fff863e4cd1]
    +                                               2297 _dispatch_group_wait_slow  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 208  [0x7fff8834dddd]
    +                                                 2297 semaphore_wait_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff85b6aa56]
```

Comment: Do you have solution for this issue ?